# SQL multiple calculation in table creation

Tags: t-sql, sql-insert

I'm trying to create a table with multiple calculation.

I have a base table from which I would like to collect data and insert into the new table. The next columns are calculated based on the base table. So the first few columns are based on the original table, one part of it exactly the same, other part is calculated.

These works fine, however the last 2 columns are not. The calculation of these would be based on the calculated field of the new table.

Can it be solved within one step? Should I use update? As far as I know ranking is not working with that.

```
INSERT INTO [RAW_NBA_TeamSimpleRating]
(
      [Team]
      ,[Game_total]
      ,[ORtg_avg]
      ,[DRtg_avg]
      ,[ORtg_rank]
      ,[ORtg_cluster]
 
      )
SELECT
    [Team]
    ,[Game]
    ,AVG ([ORtg]) OVER (PARTITION BY Team ORDER BY RowNumber rows between 81 preceding and current row) as ORtg_avg
    ,AVG ([DRtg]) OVER (PARTITION BY Team ORDER BY RowNumber rows between 81 preceding and current row) as DRtg_avg

    ,RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY [RAW_NBA_TeamSimpleRating].[Game_total] ORDER BY [RAW_NBA_TeamSimpleRating].[ORtg_avg] Desc)

    ,CASE
        WHEN RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY [RAW_NBA_TeamSimpleRating].[Game_total] ORDER BY [RAW_NBA_TeamSimpleRating].[ORtg_avg] DESC) > 10 THEN 'Bottom'
        WHEN RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY [RAW_NBA_TeamSimpleRating].[Game_total] ORDER BY [RAW_NBA_TeamSimpleRating].[ORtg_avg] DESC) <= 10 THEN 'TOP'
    END

FROM [WRK_NBA_TeamTable]
```

Comment: You just need to wrap your query with an outer select - ie a `derived table`

Comment: Did you get any message?

Comment: How about setting `ORtg_cluster` as a  [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15) ?

Comment: yes, the error message is: The multi-part identifier "RAW_NBA_TeamSimpleRating.Game_total" could not be bound.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap your query you can use the values from the inner select, such as

```
select Team, Game, ORtg_avg, DRtg_avg, [Rank],
    case
      when [Rank] > 10 then 'Bottom'
      when [Rank] <= 10 then 'TOP'
   end as ORtg_cluster
from (
    select Team, Game
        ,Avg (ORtg) over (partition by Team order by RowNumber rows between 81 preceding and current row) as ORtg_avg
        ,Avg (DRtg) over (partition by Team order by RowNumber rows between 81 preceding and current row) as DRtg_avg
        ,Rank () over (partition by RAW_NBA_TeamSimpleRating.Game_total order by RAW_NBA_TeamSimpleRating.ORtg_avg desc) as [Rank]
    from WRK_NBA_TeamTable  
)s
```

Comment: I guess the problem is the same than before: 
The multi-part identifier "RAW_NBA_TeamSimpleRating.Game_total" could not be bound.